# Convert a LVM into a RAID 5

Tags: ubuntu, raid, lvm

I have 3 disk (600GB) only one in use. is possible convert into a RAID5 without need a external disk

my system is:

- Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
- 3 x SAS 600GB Hitachi (only 1 in use in a VG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really only have used on of the three disks, it's quite easy:

- Remove the other two from the LVM VG if they are part of it.
- Remove the LVM partitions on the disks, add RAID ones instead
- Create a RAID5 with only two disks and the third one missing. Your device names might be different.

  ```
  mdadm --create -f /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 missing
  ```
- Make a file system on the RAID and mount it.
- Copy the data from the LVM volume
- Destroy the VG, remove partition and make RAID partition
- add it to the RAID

  ```
  mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sda1
  ```

This is a somewhat dangerous process as your data is striped among two disks until the third is added to the RAID and the sync is finished. Have a backup ready.

Comment: is possible add the new raid (2 disk) into the volume group of the other disk with this way i can use pvmove for move all LV without pain

Comment: It should be possible to add `/dev/md0` to the VG (`pvcreate` and `vgextend`), do a `pvmove` and then remove the last single disk from the VG to add it to the raid but I wouldn't call this "without pain".

Comment: why not call it "without pain"? any complications can occur?

Comment: It just complicates stuff more, which is a Bad Thing (TM). If you do everything right, it will likely work, but the likelihood for both human and system error grows with every additional required step. Besides, an `rsync` to a new file system might be faster as a `pvmove`, as `pvmove` will copy the entire disk, sector by sector, whereas `rsync` just copy files.

Comment: Finally: **I was really serious when I suggested to have a backup ready.**

Comment: really appreciate your advice, I'm making a full backup of all my VG to avoid any loss before doing this step

Comment: if pvmove fails, with a pvmove --abort i can restore without problems (I have a full backup in a external disk)